# Android NDK cant compile a sample app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

What is causing this strang error when i try to run ndk-build on my project?  I followed this example verbatim http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/
I am able to compile and run android examples that came with the NDK perfectly

1. There are no unnecessary spaces in my make file
2. My project properties seem ok in eclipse
3. I dont have a generated obj. folder or header files in my project.
4. All the project files are located in the default workspace (only the ndk-build is located in the ndk folder)

Error in question:

```
C:\Users\adam.kim\workspace\UWBcontroler\jni> C:/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build
make: *** No rule to make target `C:/Users/adam.kim/workspace/UWBcontroler//jni/
native.c', needed by `C:/Users/adam.kim/workspace/UWBcontroler//obj/local/armeab
i/objs/adamsndk/native.o'.  Stop.
```

Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
    LOCAL_MODULE    := adamsndk
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

add-application.mk (this is in the ndk folder that was created during installation)
only line i changed was the APP_PIE APP_PLATFORM  from sdk 14 to 8

```
APP_DEBUG := $(strip $(NDK_DEBUG))
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),0)
  APP_DEBUG:= false
endif
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),1)
  APP_DEBUG := true
endif
ifdef APP_DEBUG
  ifneq (,$(filter-out true false,$(APP_DEBUG)))
    $(call __ndk_warning,NDK_DEBUG is defined to the unsupported value '$(NDK_DEBUG)', will be ignored!)
  endif
endif

include $(_application_mk)

$(call check-required-vars,$(NDK_APP_VARS_REQUIRED),$(_application_mk))

_map := NDK_APP.$(_app)

# strip the 'lib' prefix in front of APP_MODULES modules
APP_MODULES := $(call strip-lib-prefix,$(APP_MODULES))

APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(strip $(APP_PROJECT_PATH))
ifndef APP_PROJECT_PATH
    APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)
endif

# check whether APP_PLATFORM is defined. If not, look for project.properties in
# the $(APP_PROJECT_PATH) and extract the value with awk's help. If nothing is here,
# revert to the default value (i.e. "android-3").
#
APP_PLATFORM := $(strip $(APP_PLATFORM))
ifndef APP_PLATFORM
    _local_props := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/project.properties))
    ifndef _local_props
        # NOTE: project.properties was called default.properties before
        _local_props := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/default.properties))
    endif
    ifdef _local_props
        APP_PLATFORM := $(strip $(shell $(HOST_AWK) -f $(BUILD_AWK)/extract-platform.awk $(call host-path,$(_local_props))))
        $(call ndk_log,  Found APP_PLATFORM=$(APP_PLATFORM) in $(_local_props))
    else
        APP_PLATFORM := android-3
        $(call ndk_log,  Defaulted to APP_PLATFORM=$(APP_PLATFORM))
    endif
endif

# SPECIAL CASES:
# 1) android-6 and android-7 are the same thing as android-5
# 2) android-10 .. 13 is the same thing as android-9
#
APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL := $(strip $(subst android-,,$(APP_PLATFORM)))
ifneq (,$(filter 6 7,$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL)))
    APP_PLATFORM := android-5
    $(call ndk_log,  Adjusting APP_PLATFORM android-$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL) to $(APP_PLATFORM))
endif
ifneq (,$(filter 10 11 12 13,$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL)))
    APP_PLATFORM := android-9
    $(call ndk_log,  Adjusting APP_PLATFORM android-$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL) to $(APP_PLATFORM))
endif

# If APP_PIE isn't defined, set it to true for android-16 and above
#
APP_PIE := $(strip $(APP_PIE))
$(call ndk_log,  APP_PIE is $(APP_PIE))
ifndef APP_PIE
    ifneq (,$(call gte,$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL),16))
        APP_PLATFORM := android-8
        $(call ndk_log,  Adjusting APP_PLATFORM android-$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL) to $(APP_PLATFORM) and enabling -fPIE)
        APP_PIE := true
    else
        APP_PIE := false
    endif
endif

# Check that the value of APP_PLATFORM corresponds to a known platform
# If not, we're going to use the max supported platform value.
#
_bad_platform := $(strip $(filter-out $(NDK_ALL_PLATFORMS),$(APP_PLATFORM)))
ifdef _bad_platform
    $(call ndk_log,Application $(_app) targets unknown platform '$(_bad_platform)')
    APP_PLATFORM := android-$(NDK_MAX_PLATFORM_LEVEL)
    $(call ndk_log,Switching to $(APP_PLATFORM))
endif

# Check platform level (after adjustment) against android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml
#
APP_MANIFEST := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/AndroidManifest.xml))
APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL := $(strip $(subst android-,,$(APP_PLATFORM)))
ifdef APP_MANIFEST
  APP_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL := $(shell $(HOST_AWK) -f $(BUILD_AWK)/extract-minsdkversion.awk $(call host-path,$(APP_MANIFEST)))
  ifneq (,$(call gt,$(APP_PLATFORM_LEVEL),$(APP_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL)))
    $(call __ndk_warning,WARNING: APP_PLATFORM $(APP_PLATFORM) is larger than android:minSdkVersion $(APP_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL) in $(APP_MANIFEST))
  endif
endif

# Check that the value of APP_ABI corresponds to known ABIs
# 'all' is a special case that means 'all supported ABIs'
#
# It will be handled in setup-app.mk. We can't hope to change
# the value of APP_ABI is the user enforces it on the command-line
# with a call like:  ndk-build APP_ABI=all
#
# Because GNU Make makes the APP_ABI variable read-only (any assignments
# to it will be ignored)
#
APP_ABI := $(strip $(APP_ABI))
ifndef APP_ABI
    # Default ABI is 'armeabi'
    APP_ABI := armeabi
endif
ifneq ($(APP_ABI),all)
    _bad_abis := $(strip $(filter-out $(NDK_ALL_ABIS),$(APP_ABIS)))
    ifdef _bad_abis
        $(call __ndk_info,Application $(_app) targets unknown ABI '$(_bad_abis)')
        $(call __ndk_info,Please fix the APP_ABI definition in $(_application_mk))
        $(call __ndk_info,to use a set of the following values: $(NDK_ALL_ABIS))
        $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
    endif
endif

# If APP_BUILD_SCRIPT is defined, check that the file exists.
# If undefined, look in $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Android.mk
#
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(strip $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
ifdef APP_BUILD_SCRIPT
    _build_script := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT)))
    ifndef _build_script
        $(call __ndk_info,Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
        $(call __ndk_error,Aborting...)
    endif
    APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(_build_script)
    $(call ndk_log,  Using build script $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
else
    _build_script := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Android.mk))
    ifndef _build_script
        $(call __ndk_info,There is no Android.mk under $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni)
        $(call __ndk_info,If this is intentional, please define APP_BUILD_SCRIPT to point)
        $(call __ndk_info,to a valid NDK build script.)
        $(call __ndk_error,Aborting...)
    endif
    APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(_build_script)
    $(call ndk_log,  Defaulted to APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=$(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
endif

# Determine whether the application should be debuggable.
# - If APP_DEBUG is set to 'true', then it always should.
# - If APP_DEBUG is set to 'false', then it never should
# - Otherwise, extract the android:debuggable attribute from the manifest.
#
ifdef APP_DEBUG
  APP_DEBUGGABLE := $(APP_DEBUG)
  ifeq ($(NDK_LOG),1)
    ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),true)
      $(call ndk_log,Application '$(_app)' forced debuggable through NDK_DEBUG)
    else
      $(call ndk_log,Application '$(_app)' forced *not* debuggable through NDK_DEBUG)
    endif
  endif
else
  # NOTE: To make unit-testing simpler, handle the case where there is no manifest.
  APP_DEBUGGABLE := false
  ifdef APP_MANIFEST
    APP_DEBUGGABLE := $(shell $(HOST_AWK) -f $(BUILD_AWK)/extract-debuggable.awk $(call host-path,$(APP_MANIFEST)))
  endif
  ifeq ($(NDK_LOG),1)
    ifeq ($(APP_DEBUGGABLE),true)
      $(call ndk_log,Application '$(_app)' *is* debuggable)
    else
      $(call ndk_log,Application '$(_app)' is not debuggable)
    endif
  endif
endif

# LOCAL_BUILD_MODE will be either release or debug
#
# If APP_OPTIM is defined in the Application.mk, just use this.
#
# Otherwise, set to 'debug' if android:debuggable is set to TRUE,
# and to 'release' if not.
#
ifneq ($(APP_OPTIM),)
    # check that APP_OPTIM, if defined, is either 'release' or 'debug'
    $(if $(filter-out release debug,$(APP_OPTIM)),\
        $(call __ndk_info, The APP_OPTIM defined in $(_application_mk) must only be 'release' or 'debug')\
        $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)\
    )
    $(call ndk_log,Selecting optimization mode through Application.mk: $(APP_OPTIM))
else
    ifeq ($(APP_DEBUGGABLE),true)
        $(call ndk_log,Selecting debug optimization mode (app is debuggable))
        APP_OPTIM := debug
    else
        $(call ndk_log,Selecting release optimization mode (app is not debuggable))
        APP_OPTIM := release
    endif
endif

APP_CFLAGS := $(strip $(APP_CFLAGS))
APP_LDFLAGS := $(strip $(APP_LDFLAGS))

# Check that APP_STL is defined. If not, use the default value (system)
# otherwise, check that the name is correct.
APP_STL := $(strip $(APP_STL))
ifndef APP_STL
    APP_STL := system
else
    $(call ndk-stl-check,$(APP_STL))
endif

$(if $(call get,$(_map),defined),\
  $(call __ndk_info,Weird, the application $(_app) is already defined by $(call get,$(_map),defined))\
  $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)\
)

$(call set,$(_map),defined,$(_application_mk))

# Record all app-specific variable definitions
$(foreach __name,$(NDK_APP_VARS),\
  $(call set,$(_map),$(__name),$($(__name)))\
)

# Record the Application.mk for debugging
$(call set,$(_map),Application.mk,$(_application_mk))

NDK_ALL_APPS += $(_app)
```

Comment: It can't find native.c - perhaps you put that in the wrong folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one reason or another, on this machine i had to create the proper file system before running the ndk-build.  On other machines I didn't have to manually create folders beforehand (such as obj, local, armeabi, etc.) but on this machine i had to BEFORE running ndk-build... Hopefully this saves someone some time.  I'm on a Dell i7 laptop with win764 bit professional although i'n not sure how this would affect it.  I'm still very much confused about the whole thing and will accept an answer that provides some enlightenment... I'm wondering if this is a permissions thing (since ndk-build seemed to be unable to create directories) even though I do have admin rights for this machine.